# Split a string and get the last item

Tags: r

```
directory <- "/home/rstudio-doug/analysis/radhoc/revenue_model/models/fungame/trained_to_202001"
```

I would like to get "trained_to_202001" as a variable. Tried:

```
directory %>% str_split("/") %>% last()
[1] ""                  "home"              "rstudio-doug"     "analysis"          "radhoc"            "revenue_model"    
[7] "models"            "fungame"      "trained_to_202001"
```

Then tried:
directory %>% str_split("/") %>% tail(n = 1)

```
[[1]]
[1] ""                  "home"              "rstudio-doug"     "analysis"          "radhoc"            "revenue_model"    
[7] "models"            "fungame"      "trained_to_202001"
```

How can I get "trained_to_202001"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any `/` in your last part (I'd assume so), you could just go with:

```
gsub('.*\\/', '', directory)

# [1] "trained_to_202001"
```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured it out by replacing flatten() above with unlist()

Answer (score 1):

We can use `basename`

```
basename(directory)
#[1] "trained_to_202001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unlist` before using `last` like shown below

`directory %>% str_split("/") %>% unlist %>% last()`

```
[1] "trained_to_202001"
```